# Setting custom contrasts in R

Tags: r, anova, spss, contrasts

I have a data as follows.

```
data <- structure(list(Loc = structure(c(17L, 27L, 33L, 6L, 39L, 10L, 
                                         9L, 11L, 36L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 34L, 45L, 18L, 15L, 29L, 31L, 14L, 
                                         40L, 44L, 19L, 1L, 22L, 3L, 32L, 16L, 21L, 20L, 13L, 12L, 25L, 
                                         35L, 8L, 24L, 41L, 30L, 23L, 7L, 37L, 42L, 26L, 28L, 38L, 43L, 
                                         17L, 27L, 33L, 6L, 39L, 10L, 9L, 11L, 36L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 34L, 45L, 
                                         18L, 15L, 29L, 31L, 14L, 40L, 44L, 19L, 1L, 22L, 3L, 32L, 16L, 
                                         21L, 20L, 13L, 12L, 25L, 35L, 8L, 24L, 41L, 30L, 23L, 7L, 37L, 
                                         42L, 26L, 28L, 38L, 43L), .Label = c("Hpan100786", "Hpan100794", 
                                                                              "Hpan107006", "Hpan109517", "Hpan109543", "Hpan109546", "Hpan109549p", 
                                                                              "Hpan109551", "Hpan109552", "Hpan109553", "Hpan109556", "Hpan112828", 
                                                                              "Hpan113401", "Hpan114525", "Hpan116055", "Hpan14479", "Hpan25167", 
                                                                              "Hpan2573", "Hpan34342", "Hpan36372", "Hpan39020", "Hpan39039", 
                                                                              "Hpan4496", "Hpan6103", "Hpan61434", "Hpan65773", "Hpan76756", 
                                                                              "Hpan93602", "Hpan95269", "Hpan95278", "Lpan15539", "Lpan16561", 
                                                                              "Lpan16823", "Lpan21755", "Lpan24060", "Lpan24994", "Lpan25763", 
                                                                              "Lpan3", "Lpan501186", "Lpan501220", "Lpan501263", "Lpan501286", 
                                                                              "Lpan501468", "Lpan501493", "Lpan501531"), class = "factor"), 
                       Class = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                           1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                           2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                           3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                           1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                           2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                           3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Good", "Medium", "Poor"), class = "factor"), 
                       Rep = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                         1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                         1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                         1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                         2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                         2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                         2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("R1", "R2"), class = "factor"), 
                       y = c(1202, 686, 921, 705, 1060, 642, 996, 1154, 1195, 692, 
                             1045, 1008, 1107, 1195, 1267, 703, 1371, 1122, 992, 1721, 
                             989, 503, 1023, 740, 1169, 716, 625, 1403, 783, 1182, 1411, 
                             851, 1191, 1444, 1643, 1185, 1635, 1525, 1162, 1472, 626, 
                             575, 721, 849, 867, 1178, 703, 845, 689, 1011, 659, 1022, 
                             1203, 1202, 716, 1004, 1004, 1082, 1176, 1248, 719, 1328, 
                             1185, 966, 1685, 1050, 510, 998, 721, 1173, 718, 614, 1392, 
                             767, 1035, 1430, 902, 1225, 1451, 1615, 1157, 1659, 1506, 
                             1151, 1466, 618, 583, 736, 885, 876)), .Names = c("Loc", 
                                                                               "Class", "Rep", "y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                         -90L))
```

I am trying to do ANOVA with planned contrasts in R using `aov`. The 45 `Loc` belong to 3 different `Class`. I want to compare the `Loc` in one class with those in another `Class`. I am trying to follow [A (sort of) Complete Guide to Contrasts in R](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/65059_586f394d8eb84f84b1baaf56ffb6b47f.html) steps for "Running Fewer than J-1 Contrasts for J Groups".

```
#Creation of contrast matrix
# reorder the levels of `Loc` according to `Class`
data$Loc <- factor(data$Loc, levels = unique(data[order(data$Class), "Loc"]))

c1 <- c(rep(1/15, 15), rep(-1/15, 15), rep(0, 15)) # Good vs Med
c2 <- c(rep(1/15, 15), rep(0, 15), rep(-1/15, 15)) # Good vs Poor
c3 <- c(rep(0, 15), rep(1/15, 15), rep(-1/15, 15)) # Med vs Poor

# Specify the contrasts
mat <- cbind(c1, c2, c3)

options(contrasts = c("contr.helmert", "contr.poly"))
m1 <- aov(y ~ Loc, data = data)
summary(m1)
            Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)    
Loc         44 8547697  194266   292.3 <2e-16 ***
Residuals   45   29910     665                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

m2 <- aov(y ~ Loc, data = data, contrasts=list(Loc = mat))
summary.aov(m2, split=list(Loc=list("Good Vs Med"=1,
                                     "Good Vs Poor" = 2,
                                     "Med Vs Poor"=3)))

                    Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
Loc                  2  483311  241656   2.597 0.0802 .
  Loc: Good Vs Med   1    1363    1363   0.015 0.9039  
  Loc: Good Vs Poor  1  481948  481948   5.180 0.0253 *
  Loc: Med Vs Poor   1                                 
Residuals           87 8094296   93038                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

The third contrast is missing.

Also the contrast c3 effect is missing

```
names(m2$coefficients)
[1] "(Intercept)" "Locc1"       "Locc2"       "Locc3"      
names(m2$effects)
 [1] "(Intercept)" "Locc1"       "Locc2"       ""            ""            ""           
 [7] ""            ""            ""            ""            ""            ""           
[13] ""            ""            ""            ""            ""            ""           
[19] ""            ""            ""            ""            ""            ""           
[25] ""            ""            ""            ""            ""            ""           
[31] ""            ""            ""            ""            ""            ""           
[37] ""            ""            ""            ""            ""            ""           
[43] ""            ""            ""
```

How to get the appropirate comparisons here? What am I doing wrong in specifying the contrast matrix?

In SPSS I can do the comparisons using the following syntax

```
UNIANOVA y BY Loc
/METHOD=SSTYPE(3)
/INTERCEPT=INCLUDE
/CRITERIA=ALPHA(0.05)
/LMATRIX = "Good_vs_Med" y -15, 15, -15, 15, 15, 15, 0, 0, 15, 15, 15, 0, -15, -15, -15, -15, 15, 15, -15, -15, -15, -15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 0, -15, 0, -15, -15, 15, 15, 0, 15, 0, 0, 15, -15, 0, 0, 0, -15, 15;
/LMATRIX = "Good_vs_Poor" y 0, 15, 0, 15, 15, 15, -15, -15, 15, 15, 15, -15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, -15, -15, -15, -15, 15, -15, 0, -15, 0, 0, 15, 15, -15, 15, -15, -15, 15, 0, -15, -15, -15, 0, 15;
/LMATRIX = "Med_vs_Poor" y 15, 0, 15, 0, 0, 0, -15, -15, 0, 0, 0, -15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 0, 0, 15, 15, 15, 15, -15, -15, -15, -15, 0, -15, 15, -15, 15, 15, 0, 0, -15, 0, -15, -15, 0, 15, -15, -15, -15, 15, 0;
/PRINT = TEST(LMATRIX)
/DESIGN=y
```

Comment: At a guess R insists on only using 2 df for comparing 3 groups and SPSS does not. You might get better answers on an R site.

Comment: Is it because the contrast effect `Locc3` is missing in model (`names(m2$effects)`)

Comment: You have only 2 degrees of freedom. 3 groups, 1 grand mean, 2 degrees of freedom. Are you testing the hypothesis $\mu_1=\mu_2=\mu_3$ (sane) or $\mu_1=\mu_2=\mu_3=0$ (not clear).

Comment: @AdamO There are 45 levels in Loc, so 44 df (as is clear in `m1`). Something is going wrong when aov() estimates `m2`. Interesting problem!

Comment: A related post on SO (unfortunately without a useful answer): [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31818174/custom-contrasts-in-r-contrast-coefficient-matrix-or-contrast-matrix-coding-s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31818174/custom-contrasts-in-r-contrast-coefficient-matrix-or-contrast-matrix-coding-s)

Comment: @AdamO  The hypothesis to be tested would be (1)$\mu_1 = \mu_2 = .......= \mu_{45}$; (2)$\mu_{Good} = \mu_{Medium}$; 
(3)$\mu_{Good} = \mu_{Poor}$ and (4)$\mu_{Medium} = \mu_{Poor}$

Comment: I'm the author of the tutorial you're using, by the way. :) I'm glad it's still getting some use! Perhaps I'll update it with some follow-up information on this issue.

Comment: @RoseHartman 2 *numerator* degrees of freedom. The denominator is irrelevant until the issue of contrasts is resolved.

Comment: @Crops then the 2 level ANOVA is correct for hypothesis one, and Tukey post hoc for the next hypotheses. 2-4 are redundant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting problem! The issue is that you're basically re-coding `Loc` into a variable with three levels (corresponding to your three levels of `Class` in this case), which leaves it with only 2 degrees of freedom. R can't estimate three contrasts for a factor with three levels in a model with an intercept.

You can see this because you get 44 df in `m1` when R uses its automatic contrasts, but only 2 when you specify your own contrast matrix in `m2`. The problem is that the contrasts you're specifying create a singular matrix:

```
> contrasts(data$Loc) <- mat
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c(0.0666666666666667, 0.0666666666666667,  : 
  singular contrast matrix
```

If you modify your contrast matrix so it's not a complete coding scheme for three levels, R will go back to filling in the missing df with complementary orthogonal contrasts to the ones you specify:

```
c4 <- c(rep(0, 5), rep(1/15, 15), rep(-1/15, 15), rep(0, 10)) # made up c4
mat <- cbind(c1, c2, c3, c4)
m2 <- aov(y ~ Loc, data = data, contrasts=list(Loc = mat))
summary.aov(m2, split=list(Loc=list("Good Vs Med"=1,
                                    "Good Vs Poor" = 2,
                                    "Med vs Poor"=3)))
```

Results:

```
                    Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
Loc                  3  683581  227860   2.482 0.0663 .
  Loc: Good Vs Med   1    1363    1363   0.015 0.9033  
  Loc: Good Vs Poor  1  481948  481948   5.250 0.0244 *
  Loc: Med vs Poor   1  200270  200270   2.182 0.1433  
Residuals           86 7894026   91791                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Note that when you specify the contrasts within the model call (`aov`), it limits the df for the predictor to the number of contrasts you ran - 1, and any additional SS goes into the residual SS. Above, I used a pretty gross hack to get 3 df (so we could see all of your comparisons) by specifying 4 contrasts.

If you specify your contrasts as an attribute of the variable `Loc` before running the model, R will attempt to auto-fill the rest of the contrast matrix out to the full 44 df, but it still can't in this case because the matrix is singular.

## A better approach

It sounds like you're actually trying to get comparisons among the levels of `Class`, not `Loc`, but you want all three possible comparisons so you're trying to get `Loc` to do it for you since `Class` can't. **Instead of running contrasts, you should be looking at pairwise comparisons for `Class`.** You can do that with `pairwise.t.test` from the `stats` package, but I prefer the `lsmeans` package for nicer formatting and more flexibility.

```
m3 <- aov(y ~ Class, data = data)
library(lsmeans)
```

You can then use `lsmeans` functions to compare your different classes on `y`. The default output gives you the estimated marginal means (which is the same as the raw means, in this case, since you don't have any covariates) with 95%CI around them:

```
> lsmeans(m3, ~ Class)
 Class     lsmean       SE df  lower.CL upper.CL
 Good    987.2333 55.68898 87  876.5454 1097.921
 Medium  996.7667 55.68898 87  886.0788 1107.455
 Poor   1147.2333 55.68898 87 1036.5454 1257.921
```

You can see all pairwise comparisons by wrapping that with the `pairs` function:

```
> pairs(lsmeans(m3, ~ Class))
 contrast         estimate       SE df t.ratio p.value
 Good - Medium   -9.533333 78.75612 87  -0.121  0.9920
 Good - Poor   -160.000000 78.75612 87  -2.032  0.1107
 Medium - Poor -150.466667 78.75612 87  -1.911  0.1418

P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 3 estimates
```

It defaults to a sensible post hoc adjustment ([Tukey's HSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tukey%27s_range_test)), but you can change that with the `adjust` argument if you want. If you turn off the adjustment for multiple comparisons, you'll see that one of your comparisons is significant with uncorrected p-values:

```
> pairs(lsmeans(m3, ~ Class), adjust = "none")
 contrast         estimate       SE df t.ratio p.value
 Good - Medium   -9.533333 78.75612 87  -0.121  0.9039
 Good - Poor   -160.000000 78.75612 87  -2.032  0.0452
 Medium - Poor -150.466667 78.75612 87  -1.911  0.0594
```

This is a **much** more sensible way to compare each of the three classes in your data.

Comment: How do I set c4? Is it arbitrary? If I am using `c4 <- c(rep(-1/15, 15), rep(1/30, 30))`, again it is a singular matrix.

Comment: If I am using each contrast individually, I am getting the sum of squares as in SPSS. `mat <- cbind(c3)
m2 <- aov(y ~ Loc, data = data, contrasts=list(Loc = mat))
summary.aov(m2, split=list(Loc=list("Good Vs Med"=1,
                                    "Good Vs Poor" = 2,
                                    "Med vs Poor"=3)))`

Comment: @Crops as long as you include c1, c2, and c3 as you have them, you'll end up with a singular matrix. Adding an arbitrary c4 will get R to print results for you, but the F-ratios will depend on the residual and so may change depending on the c4 you create --- not ideal. I don't recommend you test the comparisons with contrasts. Instead, use pairwise comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

My advice is to forget contrasts in *aov* and use the *lsmeans* or *multcomp* packages instead.  They allow you to run as many contrasts as you would like without being limited by degrees of freedom.  They also allow you to run a test on contrasts that span more than one line.

The follow page has examples. http://rcompanion.org/rcompanion/h_01.html. (Caveat:  I am the author of this page.)